# How to write comment for a table using gorm?

Tags: go, orm, comments, grails-orm

How can I write comment for a table using gorm? (not for the field)

Is there any methods for the table comment like `TableName() string` for the table name?

```golang
type Human struct {
    ID int
}

func (h *Human) TableName() string {
    return "human_table"
}

func (h *Human) Comment() string {
    return "this is table for human"
}

func main() {
    //
    db.AutoMigrate(&Human{})
    //
}
```

- I am using postgresql

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar to PostgreSQL, but in MySQL, you can add table comment by `gorm:table_options`, as described in https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Auto-Migration:

```golang
if err := Db.Set("gorm:table_options", "ENGINE InnoDB COMMENT 'users'").
    AutoMigrate(&User{}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := Db.Set("gorm:table_options", "ENGINE InnoDB COMMENT 'groups'").
    AutoMigrate(&Group{}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: this can only migrate table 1 by 1.